# How to create a dialog window after countdown/timer in java?

Tags: java, javafx, timer, countdown

I would like to have an open dialog window every "n" seconds.

I tried to use "Timer". I had the following error:

```java
"Exception in threadTimer-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; 
currentThread = Timer-0"
```

from this I understood that I can not create other windows on threads that is not the javaFX thread.

```java
private Integer animationTime;
private void routine(Integer time) throws Exception{
    animationTime = time;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timeline = new Timeline (new KeyFrame (Duration.seconds(1), evt -> 
    updateAnimation(time)) );
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {// repeat over and over 
        @Override
        public void run() {
            alert= new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Alert title");
            alert.setHeaderText("Alert...");
            alert.setContentText("....");
            alert.show();
            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
            if(result.get() == ButtonType.OK ){
                try {
                    routine(time);
                }
                catch (Exception e){}
            }
        }
    }, time*1000, time*1000);
}

private void updateAnimation(Integer time){
    if(animationTime.equals(0)){
         timeline.stop();
    }
    textTime.setText("Minutes: " + animationTime.toString());
    animationTime -= 1;
}
```

How can I fix it?

> Update 30/12/2018

There is a new bug

```java
timeline.setOnFinished((e)->{

         Alert alert= new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
         alert.setTitle("Alert title");
         alert.setHeaderText("Alert...");
         alert.setContentText("....");
         alert.show();
         Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
         if(result.get() == ButtonType.OK ){
                try {
                    routine(time);
                }
                catch (Exception ex){}
          }
}
```

> ```java
>      Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
> ```
>
> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: showAndWait is not allowed during
>   animation or layout processing

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `Timer`. Use [Timeline#setOnFinished](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#setOnFinished-javafx.event.EventHandler-) method:

```
timeline.setOnFinished((e)->{

         Alert alert= new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
         alert.setTitle("Alert title");
         alert.setHeaderText("Alert...");
         alert.setContentText("....");
         alert.show();
         Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
         if(result.get() == ButtonType.OK ){
                try {
                    routine(time);
                }
                catch (Exception ex){}
          }
 });
```

Comment: I solved part of the problem, now a new bug comes out
    ...
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait(); // line bug

    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: showAndWait is not allowed during animation 
    or layout processing